# SQL How to return All products sold in last 30 days Include non sellers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying return a best sellers list for the last 30 days for a category ordered by sum quantity

If the category has 10 products and only 5 have sold I want to return all 10 products ordered by most sold.

Here's what I have so far

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
    ORDER BY 
     ISNULL(SUM(B.quantity),0) desc
         )AS RowNumber
,
a.productID, 
ISNULL(SUM(B.quantity),0) AS countquantity,
a.product

FROM
products a
left join savedDetails b on a.productid =b.productid
left join Category d on d.Categorysec = a.CategoryID 

WHERE 
(a.pinstock='1' and a.BrandID = '7' and a.categoryid = '15' and (b.despatchdate >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()) OR b.despatchdate IS NULL))

GROUP BY 
a.productid,
a.CategoryID, 
a.product
```

Just need some help as this only returns products sold or never sold. If a product sold 32 days again it doesn't get returned.

Thanks

Comment: sample data and expected output would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move this clause:

```
and (b.despatchdate >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
```

To the first left join clause. Putting it in the where clause makes SQL Server evaluate values on *actual* rows, turning your left join into an inner join. (This also makes the `IS NULL` check redundant.)

So:

```
...
FROM
products a
left join savedDetails b on a.productid =b.productid
    and (b.despatchdate >= DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
left join Category d on d.Categorysec = a.CategoryID 
WHERE 
(a.pinstock='1' and a.BrandID = '7' and a.categoryid = '15'
GROUP BY 
...
```